# Angular throws Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

My code is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app=angular.module("App",['ngRoute']);
  app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/',{controller:MainController,templateUrl:'/html/main.html'}).otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});

  }]);

 app.controller('MainController',  function($scope){
 $scope.a={};
 })
</script>
```

Above code throws Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr].

Can some help me solve this.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using the release candidate for angular route and 1.3.14 for angular itself?

Comment: sorry ,i am new to angular.just started learning .guess the i book i am using is bit outdated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$routeProvider.when('/',{controller:'MainController',templateUrl:'/html/main.html'}).otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
```

`MainController` must be string but you have specified it as variable

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vugaho/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**